# After upgrading Apache IoTDB, why the log is still writing in the directory of older version?

Tags: upgrade, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I upgraded Apache IoTDB from Version 1.0.1 to Version 1.1.2 and packaged the data directory of Version 1.0.1 into `basedir` of Version 1.1.2. The cluster started successfully, but the log of the system is still written in the log directory of Version 1.0.1. Why did this happen and how can I switch this writing to Version 1.1.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `logback-datanode` file in the `conf` directory of Apache IoTDB, and change it to an absolute path. For example, try to set `appender class="ch.qos.logback.core,rolling.RollingFileAppender<file>$(IOTDB HOME)/logs/log datanode info.log</file>`.